# Can I extend the length of the oauth session using Yahoo's PHP SDK?

Tags: oauth, sdk, yahoo

So I am using https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php instead of the "php5" version just because they're both frankly a mess and this one was slightly less messy.

The issue is once a user logs in the login expires after an hour of the login.  Doesn't matter if the user is actively using the site or not in the interim, they are still forced to re-login once an hour.

Couldn't find any documentation on this, any suggestions would be welcomed.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is possible with Yahoo! Social SDK - PHP, We too came across the similar problem a year ago, using the same git Repo. you are using.

We used [GIGYA](http://developers.gigya.com/010_Developer_Guide/10_UM360/030_Social_Login) after that and it works like a charm with yahoo authentication. 
See if its helpful to you too.

Answer (score 2):

The official Yahoo developer documentation indeed confirms that "You can use the Access Token for one hour until it expires". See:

http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-refreshaccesstoken.html

Then it went on to say that "To get a new Access Token for continued use, use the same expired token and the get_token call to be provided a new Access Token." There is also detailed description of how exactly to invoke this operation. The signature itself looks like:

```
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token?oauth_nonce=ef3a091928d5491624c0ac54d697124422705091
  &oauth_consumer_key=123456891011121314151617181920
  &oauth_signature_method=plaintext
  &oauth_signature=55d4cf6bf417023ce5dcc3b77132fb021cd13b21abcdef%26
  &oauth_version=1.0
  &oauth_token=AJwxz0eyXRa._q0xKlggmMSpQzYjOZyqApyhHybqPzCsDr0-
  &oauth_timestamp=1204762971
  &oauth_session_handle=ALKVBsl8DHR1rsAHSwTmAxYIsIGs3l31syRaA_aaF.RDs.MknmVM4P
```

Many OAuth provider works like this nowadays, we've successfully used the same technique with Salesforce.com and a number of other OAuth providers.

The Yahoo library is really old, even the php5 version has not seen any new commits in the last 3 years. The method described above though is available to a simple REST call, so you can actually even bypass the PHP library.